# JavaScript ArcGIS: Relative links are not working

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I want to show a link in popup template when clicking on a feature. I am using popup template:

```js
const template = {
  // autocasts as new PopupTemplate()
  title: "Trail run",
  content: "{name}<br>" +
          "<a  href='http://localhost/test.html' target='_blank'>Works</a> <br>"+
          "<a href='test.html'>Does not work</a>",
  actions: [measureThisAction]
};
```

What's interesting is that when specifying absolute path (with localhost) the link works, however when using relative path it does not work. When inspecting HTML the `href` attribute is empty for second link:

[image: HTML structure]

**Question:** How can I add relative links for popup template.

Here is full runnable example:

**index.html:**

```js
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
  <title>Popup actions | Sample | ArcGIS Maps SDK for JavaScript 4.25</title>

  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #viewDiv {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.25/esri/themes/light/main.css" />
  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.25/"></script>

  <script>
    require(["esri/Map", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer", "esri/views/MapView", "esri/geometry/geometryEngine"],
            (
                    Map,
                    FeatureLayer,
                    MapView,
                    geometryEngine
            ) => {
              // Create the Map
              const map = new Map({
                basemap: "gray-vector"
              });

              // Create the MapView
              const view = new MapView({
                container: "viewDiv",
                map: map,
                center: [-117.08, 34.1],
                zoom: 11
              });

              /*************************************************************
               * The PopupTemplate content is the text that appears inside the
               * popup. Bracketed {fieldName} can be used to reference the value
               * of an attribute of the selected feature. HTML elements can be
               * used to provide structure and styles within the content.
               **************************************************************/

                      // Add this action to the popup so it is always available in this view
              const measureThisAction = {
                        title: "Measure Length",
                        id: "measure-this",
                        image: "https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest//sample-code/popup-actions/live/Measure_Distance16.png"
                      };

              const template = {
                // autocasts as new PopupTemplate()
                title: "Trail run",
                content: "{name}<br>" +
                        "<a  href='http://localhost/test.html' target='_blank'>Works</a> <br>"+
                        "<a href='test.html'>Does not work</a>",
                actions: [measureThisAction]
              };

              const featureLayer = new FeatureLayer({
                url: "https://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/arcgis/rest/services/TrailRuns/FeatureServer/0",
                popupTemplate: template
              });

              map.add(featureLayer);

              // Execute each time the "Measure Length" is clicked
              function measureThis() {
                const geom = view.popup.selectedFeature.geometry;
                const initDistance = geometryEngine.geodesicLength(geom, "miles");
                const distance = parseFloat(Math.round(initDistance * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
                view.popup.content =
                        view.popup.selectedFeature.attributes.name +
                        "<div style='background-color:DarkGray;color:white'>" +
                        distance +
                        " miles.</div>";
              }

              // Event handler that fires each time an action is clicked.
              view.popup.on("trigger-action", (event) => {
                // Execute the measureThis() function if the measure-this action is clicked
                if (event.action.id === "measure-this") {
                  measureThis();
                }
              });
            });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="viewDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**test.html:**

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the HTML sanitizer is sanitizing and escaping strings according to the ArcGIS Online supported HTML specification: https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/supported-html.htm

You can create a new `a` element and add this to a `div` which will represent the popup content. See the following code example: https://codepen.io/laurenb14/pen/zYJqzYp?editors=1000

Refer to this blog for more details on the HTML sanitizer: https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/js-api-arcgis/mapping/using-html-with-popups-in-the-arcgis-api-for-javascript/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Is it also possible to use fieldInfos when using this method (for date format, digit places, ...) or do I have to do that manually?

Comment: For anyone else wondering: `intl.formatNumber` from `esri/intl` can be used to achieve the same behaviour as `fieldInfos`.